# cmd msbuild errorlevel is always 0

Tags: cmd, msbuild, errorlevel

I have this code in my build.bat file

```
for /R %~dp0 %%A In (*.sln) do (
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe %%A /t:rebuild /nologo /verbosity:minimal /flp:Verbosity=detailed;LogFile=%~dp0\Logs.txt;append=true /m /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform="Any CPU" /p:VisualStudioVersion="12.0"
if not %errorlevel%==0 set Failed+=1
pause)
```

My problem is that %errorlevel% always 0 even when log file have errors and warnings.

Comment: For the failing cases what is the value of ERRORLEVEL before your condition i.e. could you temporarily add ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% before your if statement.

Comment: Use either `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and `!errorlevel!` instead of `%errorlevel%` or (better) return to `If ErrorLevel 1` syntax. Setting [EnabledDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) will cause each variable to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time: parsing, the command interpreter evaluates variables _line-by_line_ and/or _command_by_command_ but all code block in `()` parentheses considers to be one command. On the other hand, `If ErrorLevel 1` should to be read as _if_ `ErrorLevel` _is greater than or equal to_ `1` thus _not equal to_ `0` (_zero_)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still have issue, as I see always 0 in errorlevel. Can you please provide final version of my code as answer?

Comment: Can someone provide me final version of code? I think that I already tested all possible variants but no results.

Comment: So I have no working variant, please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comment of JozefZ helped me:

Use either SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion and !errorlevel! instead of %errorlevel% or (better) return to If ErrorLevel 1 syntax. Setting EnabledDelayedExpansion will cause each variable to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time: parsing, the command interpreter evaluates variables line-by_line and/or command_by_command but all code block in () parentheses considers to be one command. On the other hand, If ErrorLevel 1 should to be read as if ErrorLevel is greater than or equal to 1 thus not equal to 0

Answer (score 5):

Took me a bit to sort this out but this is what worked for me:

```
msbuild mySolution.sln
if errorlevel 1 exit /b errorlevel
```

I did not need to use `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: Simplest option!